# What could cause an intermittent time out in WCF duplex service?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, duplex

I have created a simple WCF duplex service as a proof-of-concept/learning exercise, defined as follows:

```
// web service definition
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IDuplexClientCallback))]
public interface IDuplexWebService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Command(CommandRequest command);
}

// service implementation decorated with:
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]

// callback contract
public interface IDuplexClientCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Send(string message);
}

// callback implementation decorated with:
[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

The reason for requiring duplex is that the Service is required to send unsolicited updates to connected Clients. The normal cycle of usage is:

1. Client calls Command() service method (does not wait for synchronous reply).
2. The Service queues the command for processing.
3. The Service respond to the Client via Send() when processing is complete.

This is working as it should quite often, but occasionally the Send() callback from Service to Client blocks for 60 seconds (times out), resulting in the Service being unable to accept new commands. There doesn't seem to be much pattern to when this occurs, there can be as few as two and as many as twenty successful commands in between blocked ones.

Each Client creates and caches one Channel to communicate with the service. Likewise, the Service creates and caches one CallbackChannel per Client. I'm using wsHttpBinding with largely default settings (relatively new to WCF). By debugging I have determined that the channels are not being prematurely closed. The implementation of the Client Callback simply writes the received message to the console.

I have added some logging statements on both Server and Client which should hopefully demonstrate the issue:

Successful command, which you can see executes very quickly:

```
17:12:35->INFO: [CLIENT] Submitting command: hello world 
17:12:35->INFO: [SERVER] Received command request.
17:12:35->INFO: [SERVER] Queuing action. 
17:12:35->INFO: [SERVER] Action queued, exiting. 
17:12:35->INFO: [SERVER] Processing complete. Sending response... 
17:12:35->INFO: [SERVER] Finished sending response. Took: 0.0068685 seconds. 
17:12:35->INFO: [CLIENT] Received response of length 21.
```

Command which gets blocked:

```
17:12:49->INFO: [CLIENT] Submitting command: hello moon
17:12:49->INFO: [SERVER] Received command request.
17:12:49->INFO: [SERVER] Queuing action.
17:12:49->INFO: [SERVER] Action queued, exiting.
17:12:49->INFO: [SERVER] Processing complete. Sending response...
17:12:49->INFO: [CLIENT] Received response of length 21.
17:12:51->INFO: [CLIENT] Submitting command: hello mars
17:12:51->INFO: [SERVER] Received command request.
17:12:51->INFO: [SERVER] Queuing action.
17:12:51->INFO: [SERVER] Action queued, exiting.
17:13:49->INFO: [SERVER] Finished sending response. Took: 60.0077729 seconds. ('hello moon')
17:13:49->INFO: [SERVER] Processing complete. Sending response...
17:13:49->INFO: [SERVER] Finished sending response. Took: 0.0076397 seconds. ('hello mars')
17:13:49->INFO: [CLIENT] Received response of length 21.
```

The sending of the response to 'hello moon' here has taken 60 seconds (during which time another command has been queued). The figure of 60 seconds here has to be relevent - something is blocking and timing out. You can also see that the Client *has* received the response almost instantly, yet the Server does not register the send operation complete for 60 seconds.

I've also enabled tracing and found this error being thrown. It seems odd to me that a one-way operation would time out waiting for a reply.

> System.TimeoutException: The HTTP request to
>   '*[localhost-url]/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/a03cfb7c-7e6d-4444-9914-11921f85c277/89a796b2-aad7-49ad-8426-c2a91ddf46c0*'
>   has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:59.9980000. The time
>   allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer
>   timeout. at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestOneWayChannelFactory.RequestOutputChannel.OnSend(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)

I've been trying to diagnose this all day and have hit a wall. I have tried different concurrency modes for the service and the issue remains. What could the cause of this be, and what further steps can I take it to track it down? Do I need to do something to manage my connections?  Do I need to tweak some configuration? I can add more code if necessary, but this is a long question as is.

Comment: i can only guess, but it seems to me that the client is still processing the previous request and blocks all further requests. How looks the implementation of `IDuplexClientCallback`? You have to add `[CallbackBehavior(
        ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
        UseSynchronizationContext = false)]` for the implementation and it   shouldn't block anymore.

Comment: @Rabban Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that hasn't solved it.